# Showing current output from exec in Python

Tags: python, exec

I am running code as follows (copied from other topic and added `sleep`):

```
import sys
import StringIO
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old

code = """
import time
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
    time.sleep(5)
"""
with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec code

print "out:", s.getvalue()
```

When I run this code I have to wait 15 seconds until the program ends to see the output.
But what should I do to see the output of the `print` statement in each iteration of the `for` loop every 5 seconds? Not to wait 15 seconds to see the whole output.

Is this possible at all?
Is it possible to see the current output of exec?

Comment: Why do you want to write the output of exec to a StringIO? You spend extra work in caching the output, and now you want to have it uncached? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with exec. The problem has to do with you having redirected stdout to a `StringIO`. All the print statements are adding content to the `StringIO` instead of printing to the screen. Thus you do not see any output. The only line that prints something to the screen is

```
print "out:", s.getvalue()
```

which occurs after the 15 seconds of sleep.

---

```
with stdoutIO() as s:
    ...
```

redirects `stdout` to a `StringIO.StringIO`. Only after the `with` context completes is `stdout` redirected to the orginal `sys.stdout`, which prints to the terminal.

---

So to get the output from exec as the print statements occur, simply remove the `stdeoutIO` context manager:

```
import sys

code = """
import time
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
    time.sleep(5)
"""

exec code
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've posted, the context manager will yield only once when the `with` is executed. So the code has to execute first (all 15 seconds of it) and all the code output is stored within the `StringIO` object. Hence, with such code, you *cannot* obtain output as it is written.

If you want to output on the fly, you need to provide your own `file`-like class instead of `StringIO` and override the `write` method. For example (example only, very quick and dirty code):

```
import sys
import StringIO
import contextlib

class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self,stdout,stringio):
        self._stdout = stdout
        self._stringio = stringio
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        if name in ('_stdout','_stringio','write'):
            object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        else:
            return getattr(self._stringio,name)
    def write(self,data):
         self._stdout.write(data)
         self._stringio.write(data)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = Proxy(sys.stdout,stdout)
    yield sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = old

code = """
import time
i = [0,1,2]
for j in i :
    print j
    time.sleep(5)
"""

with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec code

print "out:", s.getvalue()
```

which outputs:

```
0
1
2
out: 0
1
2
```

The first three lines are printed at 5 seconds intervals. The last three in one go at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and code. I have another question. I   use wxPython to display code output. I use TextCtrl widget to do this. To display current result from code sentence should I override setvalue() method or another one?

Comment: I think you're better overriding the `write()` method of the file-like object you return from the context manager.